# Merging duplicates in arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

So i have 2 arrays like this:

```
array1 = {1,2,3,4};
array2 = {353, 588, 213, 353};
```

The numbers in array1 corresponds to the respective indexes in array2, so from this it means: 1 of 353, 2 of 588, 3 of 213, 4 of 353. I want to be able to merge the duplicates in array 2 so the final one becomes:

```
array1 = {5,2,3};
array2 = {353,588,213};
```

I was thinking about looping through but I'm thinking it's inefficient so I was hoping someone would know the most efficient way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Here's another example

```
array1 = {14,2,3,8,10,2,7,9};
array2 = {353, 588, 353, 213, 588, 213, 200, 353};

array1 = {26,12,10,7};
array2 = {353,588,213,200};
```

Comment: so you want to merge the last to the previous occurence, and likewise add up the indexes (indices?) of in array one to the first occurence?

Comment: why the first number in converted array1 is 5?

Comment: @General-Doomer it seems to be the indexes sum from the first array

Comment: Because from array2, 353 appears at the first and last, which corresponding to array1, is 1 and 4. 1+4 = 5, so the total number of times is 5 of 353

Comment: This is not based on indices. the numbers in array1 purely indicates how many of each things in array2 appears. I've added another example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a diccionary where the key is the array2's value and dictionary's value is the count:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for(int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++) {
    int index = array2[i];
    if(dic.ContainsKey(index)) {
        dic[index] += array1[i];
    } else {
        dic.Add(index, array1[i]);
    }
}
```

Then, to convert the dictionary to arrays again you only need to iterate over it:

```
array1 = new int[dic.Count];
array2 = new int[dic.Count];

int position = 0;

foreach (var kvp in dic)
{
    array1[position] = kvp.Value;
    array2[position] = kvp.Key;
    position++;
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ShCIEA)

Comment: Thank you, how would I convert this dictionary back into the 2 arrays?

Comment: Answer updated with the conversion and a runnable demo

Answer (score 4):

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FE6MWP)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var array1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
        var array2 = new int[]{353, 588, 213, 353};

        var result = array1.Zip(array2, (a1, a2)=>new {Index = a1, Value = a2})
                           .GroupBy(pair=>pair.Value).ToList();

        array2 = result.Select(gr=>gr.Key).ToArray();
        array1 = result.Select(gr=>gr.Sum(pair=>pair.Index)).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", array1));       
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", array2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to get merged data. It's easy to do with [Enumerable.Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method which produce sequence of results from corresponding elements in two sequences (array1 and array2 in your case). It will produce you pairs of elemens:

```
{ a1 = 1, a2 = 353 }
{ a1 = 2, a2 = 213 }
{ a1 = 3, a2 = 588 }
{ a1 = 4, a2 = 353 }
```

Next step is grouping with [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) by a2. It will produce you groups of pairs

```
{ Key = 353, [{ a1 = 1, a2 = 353 }, { a1 = 4, a2 = 353 }] }
{ Key = 213, [{ a1 = 2, a2 = 213 }] }
{ Key = 588, [{ a1 = 3, a2 = 588 }] }
```

Then just select what you need from each group and put results to appropriate arrays:

```
var groups = array1.Zip(array2, (a1,a2) => new { a1, a2 })
                   .GroupBy(x => x.a2)
                   .ToArray();

array1 = groups.Select(g => g.Sum(x => x.a1)).ToArray();
array2 = groups.Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array1 = new int[] { 14, 2, 3, 8, 10, 2, 7, 9 };
int[] array2 = new int[] { 353, 588, 353, 213, 588, 213, 200, 353 };

// merge
Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
int count = array1.Length;
int sum;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    int a = array1[i];
    int b = array2[i];
    dic[b] = a + (dic.TryGetValue(b, out sum) ? sum : 0);
}

int[] convertedArray1 = dic.Values.ToArray();
int[] convertedArray2 = dic.Keys.ToArray();

// result is:
// convertedArray1 = { 26, 12, 10, 7 }
// convertedArray2 = { 353, 588, 213, 200 }
```